# How to parse complex JSON using GSON and java

Tags: android, json, gson

I have this `JSON` Response

```
{
"data":{
    "last_name":"abcdef",
    "email":"xyz@zzz.com",
    "data1":{
        "data2":{
            "membership":"senior"
        },
        "Skills":[
            {
                "C":"GOOD",
                "C++":"AVERAGE",
                "JAVA":"GOOD",
                "WEB":"GOOD"
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Now I use following method to parse it through `GSON`

```
public class ABC {
    public String last_name;
    public String email;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

And then I do

let us consider JSON OBJECT is == responseObject

```
ABC obj = (ABC)responseObject  // TypeCasting
```

`obj.last_name` gives me the result for lastname 
How do I implement the array and other data1 dictionary ?

Comment: Refer this http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/

Answer (score 2):

you can use `gson` library which will make it easier to parse and it is fast also.
make following class and it will convert json into your java object

```
public class Details {

   public MyData data;

}

public class MyData{

   public String last_name;
   public String email;
   public MyData1 data1;

}

public class MyData1 {

   public MyData2 data2;
   public List<Skill> Skills;
}

public class Mydata2{

    public string membership;
}

public class Skill {

   public String C;
   public String C++;
   public String JAVA;
   public String WEB;
}

// call following statement where you want to parse
Details details= new Gson().fromJson(json, Details.class);
```

Comment: I think this should be the answer.  @kashyapkbandi, you can use `details.data.data1.Skills.JAVA` to get the value of `JAVA`.

Comment: details.data.data1.Skills.get(0).JAVA // Skills is list object so you can pass index to retrieve Skill object

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        if (object.has("data")) {
            JSONObject dataObject = object.getJSONObject("data");
            String name = "", email = "", membership = "";
            if (dataObject.has("last_name")) {
                name = dataObject.getString("last_name");
            }
            if (dataObject.has("email")) {
                email = dataObject.getString("email");
            }
            ABC abc = new ABC();
            abc.setLast_name(name);
            abc.setEmail(email);
            abc.setMembership(membership);
            if (dataObject.has("data1")) {
                JSONObject data1JsonObject = dataObject.getJSONObject("data1");
                if (data1JsonObject.has("data2")) {
                    membership = data1JsonObject.getJSONObject("data2").getString("membership");
                }

                if (data1JsonObject.has("Skills")) {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = data1JsonObject.getJSONArray("Skills");
                    Skills skills = new Skills();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject skillsJsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        if (skillsJsonObject.has("C")) {
                            skills.setC(skillsJsonObject.getString("C"));
                        }
                        if (skillsJsonObject.has("C++")) {
                            skills.setcPlusPlus(skillsJsonObject.getString("C++"));
                        }
                        if (skillsJsonObject.has("JAVA")) {
                            skills.setJava(skillsJsonObject.getString("JAVA"));
                        }
                        if (skillsJsonObject.has("WEB")) {
                            skills.setWeb(skillsJsonObject.getString("WEB"));
                        }
                    }
                    abc.setSkills(skills);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

ABC.java

```
public class ABC {
private String last_name;
private String email;
private String membership;
private Skills skills;

public String getLast_name() {
    return last_name;
}

public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
    this.last_name = last_name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getMembership() {
    return membership;
}

public void setMembership(String membership) {
    this.membership = membership;
}

public Skills getSkills() {
    return skills;
}

public void setSkills(Skills skills) {
    this.skills = skills;
}
 }
```

Skills.java

```
  public class Skills {
private String c;
private String cPlusPlus;
private String java;
private String web;

public String getC() {
    return c;
}

public void setC(String c) {
    this.c = c;
}

public String getcPlusPlus() {
    return cPlusPlus;
}

public void setcPlusPlus(String cPlusPlus) {
    this.cPlusPlus = cPlusPlus;
}

public String getJava() {
    return java;
}

public void setJava(String java) {
    this.java = java;
}

public String getWeb() {
    return web;
}

public void setWeb(String web) {
    this.web = web;
}
}
```